# Crash with lazy initialization

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, lazy-initialization

I am having problems with lazily initializing an image.  In my view controller I am trying to say if the image has not been retrieved from URL, then load it.

```
- (UIImage *)image {
    if (!self.image) {
        self.image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    ... get image data from url ...

        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:urldata];
    }
    return self.image;
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, it creates a ton of UIImage objects and crashes the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a recursive call. Never access the property in the getter or setter method of the property.

You want:

```
- (UIImage *)image {
    if (!_image) {
        _image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    ... get image data from url ...

        _image = [UIImage imageWithData:urldata];
    }

    return _image;
}
```

The call to `self.image` calls this `image` method. Therefore if you call `self.image` inside the `image` method, it calls itself recursively.

Actually you can call the setter from the getter and you can call the getter from the setter but I prefer be consistent to avoid any possible issues.